# Determining the average angle

Tags: math, angle

I'm developing an application that involves getting the camera angle in a game. The angle can be anywhere from 0-359. 0 is North, 90 is East, 180 is South, etc. I'm using an API, which has a getAngle() method in Camera class.

How would I find the average between different camera angles. The real average of 0 and 359 is  179.5. As a camera angle, that would be South, but obviously 0 and 359 are both very close to North.

Comment: Hint: Basically, you are trying to find the angle of a vector which is a sum of vectors representing your directions.

Comment: Is my math wrong, or is 1-359 not enough for a circle?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk of "averaging" angles.  If you have two angles you can bisect the arc between them, but averaging 3 or more angles is fairly meaningless unless they're relatively close together.

Comment: Yes, the angles to be averaged are all within 90 degrees of each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of it in terms of vectors. Let `θ1` and `θ2` be your two angles expressed in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). Then we can determine the x and y components of the unit vectors that are at these angles:

```
x1 = sin(θ1)
y1 = cos(θ1)

x2 = sin(θ2)
y2 = cos(θ2)
```

You can then add these two vectors, and determine the x and y components of the result:

```
x* = x1 + x2
y* = y1 + y2
```

Finally, you can determine the angle of this resulting vector:

```
θavg = tan-1(y*/x*)
```

or, even better, use `atan2` (a function supported by many languages):

```
θavg = atan2(y*, x*)
```

You will probably have to separately handle the cases where `y* = 0` *and* `x* = 0`, since this means the two vectors are pointing in exactly opposite directions (so what should the 'average' be?).

Comment: +1, this is the most "mathy" way to solve the problem, but you don't discuss what to do when the denominator is 0.

Comment: @jxh Mathy, true.  But if you are doing graphics animation, you should try to avoid transcendental functions.  They take many times as long as simple arithmetic, which is really all you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @Gene: The "simple" part of the arithmetic is not so simple when generalizing the solution to more than one angle, as the OP has asked.

Comment: @jxh The denominator being 0 is a valid case; you will receive `atan(inf)` which is `pi/2`. There's a problem when you have `0/0`, however.

Comment: @jxh It's not hard. See my solution.

Comment: @Gene: I don't see how to generalize your solution beyond bisection of one angle.

Comment: @jxh Ah, I see what you mean now.  You can't bisect more than one angle, and that confused me.  As you say you can sum as many vectors as you like.  Note your solution is more correct if you say `theta = atan2(y', x')`.  This is a programmer's group after all, and the `atan2` function is available across nearly all languages to prevent the problem of zero denominator when finding an angle from a vector.  Your solution will die if the average is a vertical vector.

Comment: @Gene Thanks for the `atan2` idea, I added that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "average".  But the normal definition is the bisector of the included acute angle. You must put both within 180 degrees of each other. There are many ways to do this, but a simple one is to increment or decrement one of the angles.  If the angles are `a` and `b`, then this will do it:

```
if (a < b)
  while (abs(a - b) > 180) a = a + 360
else
  while (abs(a - b) > 180) a = a - 360
```

Now you can compute the simple average:

```
avg = (a + b) / 2
```

Of course you may want to normalize one more time:

```
while (avg < 0) avg  = avg + 360
while (avg >= 360) avg = avg - 360
```

On your example, you'd have a=0, b=359.  The first loop would increment a to 360.  The average would be 359.5.  Of course you could round that to an integer if you like.  If you round up to 360, then the final set of loops will decrement to 0.

Note that if your angles are always normalized to [0..360) none of these loops ever execute more than once.  But they're probably good practice so that a wild argument doesn't cause your code to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You want to bisect the angles not average them.  First get the distance between them, taking the shortest way around, then divide that in half and add to one of the angles.  Eg:

```
A = 355
B = 5

if (abs(A - B) < 180) {
    Distance = abs(A - B)
    if (A < B) {
        Bisect = A + Distance / 2
    }
    else {
        Bisect = B + Distance / 2
    }
}
else {
    Distance = 360 - abs(A - B)
    if (A < B) {
        Bisect = A - Distance / 2
    }
    else {
        Bisect = B - Distance / 2
    }
}
```

Or something like that -- "Bisect" should come out to zero for the given inputs.  There are probably clever ways to make the arithmetic come out with fewer if and abs operations.

Comment: (Sashkello's comment earlier is another more general way to look at the same thing -- calculate the vector sum of the vectors represented by the angles and compute the angle of that vector.  This will work for more than 2 angles.)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you mentioned that all "angles" to be averaged are within 90 degrees to each other. I am guessing that there is really only one camera, but it moves around a lot, and you are creating some sort of picture stability mechanism for the camera POV.

In any case, there is only the special case where the camera may be in the 270-359 quadrant and the 0-89 quadrant. For all other cases, you can just take a simple average. So, you just need to detect that special case, and when it happens, treat the angles in the 270-359 quadrant as -90 to -1 instead. Then, after computing the simple average, adjust it back into the 270-359 quadrant if necessary.

In C code:

```
int quadrant (int a) {
    assert(0 <= a && a < 360);
    return a/90;
}

double avg_rays (int rays[], int num) {
    int i;
    int quads[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    double sum = 0;
    /* trivial case */
    if (num == 1) return rays[0];
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) ++quads[quadrant(rays[i])];
    if (quads[0] == 0 || quads[3] == 0) {
        /* simple case */
        for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) sum += rays[i];
        return sum/num;
    }
    /* special case */
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        if (quadrant(rays[i]) == 3) rays[i] -= 360;
        sum += rays[i];
    }
    return sum/num + (sum < 0) * 360;
}
```

This code can be optimized at the expense of clarity of purpose. When you detect the special case condition, you can fix up the `sum` after the fact. So, you can compute `sum` and figure out the special case and do the fix up in a single pass.

```
double avg_rays_opt (int rays[], int num) {
    int i;
    int quads[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    double sum = 0;
    /* trivial case */
    if (num == 1) return rays[0];
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        ++quads[quadrant(rays[i])];
        sum += rays[i];
    }
    if (quads[0] == 0 || quads[3] == 0) {
        /* simple case */
        return sum/num;
    }
    /* special case */
    sum -= quads[3]*360;
    return sum/num + (sum < 0) * 360;
}
```

I am sure it can be further optimized, but it should give you a start.