# Calculating Mean and Standard Deviation of a set of Angles in Excel

Tags: excel, average, angle, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation within excel for a set of angles. This set could look like 356,340,352,2,5,8,358 or 178,-170,180,165,-177. I know that excel has built in tools to calculate the average and standard deviations but these don't work when calculating for a set of angles as it treats 360 and 0 (or 180 and -180) as being 360 degrees apart and not equivalent.

Thanks.

Comment: why not convert the angles before applying the formula and after getting the result you can change the angle back to what ever sign or in quarter you want it to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the average angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070097/determining-the-average-angle)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate the uncertainty of an angle in "Cartesion space" - you must use polar. Proof of this is trying to average 359 degrees and 1 degree. The correct answer is 0 degrees - Cartesion space will invariably decide it is 180 degrees!  No amount of adding on angles and so forth will help "in Cartesion Space". Essentially, you establish the mean using trigonometry.  I appreciate this is an old request - if you still need more info, drop me a line.